# Deploying a python websockets server to ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, websocket

I have an application that unitilizes [the websockets library](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

It's a server that listens on a specified port. I made an HTML/JS client for it.
On my local machine everything runs fine. But I want to deploy the websockets application to my Ubuntu 14 VPS.

On the server I set up everything to run the application, I run it, but client's can't connect on specified port, they time out. According to the server logs the server doesn't receive any data from clients.

I have allowed tcp traffic throught the desired port via `ufw`.

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/Euphe/async-skeleton-murder) (the server in question is in `server.py`).

What steps are required to make the client data reach the server application?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance you seem to use localhost as server name in [server.py](https://github.com/Euphe/async-skeleton-murder/blob/master/server.py) and [client.html](https://github.com/Euphe/async-skeleton-murder/blob/master/static/client.html).

That will cause the server to only accept connections on the loopback interface which won't be reachable over the internet, and the client to connect to your local machine instead of the server.

In your `server.py` you could use the empty string as hostname to bind to all interfaces, or the correct ip address to listen on.

In your client you need to use the domain name or ip address of the server.

Comment: Nice catch. when I tried to run it I changed the host in client.html, but didn't change the host in server.py. I will try it and report on the results

Comment: I have changed host in `server.py` to an empty string, but nothing changed.

Comment: Also netstat -l shows that `*:8765` is being listened on

Comment: It's hard to say, you should check for any error messages in the client (javascript log), and check that you can generally connect to that port (e.g. by using `nc -v -l -p 8765` to listen on that port and check for incoming connections)